# Responsive layout constraining horizontal display in Lightbox2 overlay

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox, lightbox2

I use [Lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) on several sites for "galleries", and never had a problem. I am now attempting to use it with a [Simple Responsive](http://www.prowebdesign.ro/simple-responsive-template/) template (or [on Github](https://github.com/prowebdesignro/simple)), and running into a problem:

When the overlay comes up and the images "zoom" to their proper size, they are restricted horizontally -- as if the browser thinks it only has a very narrow viewport. I get the same result in FF and Chrome.

If I look at it with "Inspect Element" in Chrome, the `#lightbox` main DIV is 1265px wide. But the `.lb-outerContainer` and `.lb-dataContainer` both think the width available is 247px.

I have read through the CSS and JS as carefully as I can, but cannot spot where the problem arises. I'm hoping some other sharp eyes can spot the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is this section in the Simple Responsive Template that is causing the "problem"

```
/* RESPONSIVE IMAGES */
img{ max-width:100%; height:auto;}
```

You can remove this restriction by adding after the responsive template css

```
.lb-image {
    max-width: none;
}
```

And since you want your lightbox to be responsive add

```
.lb-outerContainer  {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

instead and all should be good!